# Ajax sending response back to php after ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, response

Suppose I have a page called form.php. I then clicked a button called "add button". This button triggers an event that got detected by a jquery function. The jquery function makes an ajax call to add.php.

Inside add.php, there is code that checks if a particular record exist in the database. If it does find that the record exists, I want to do the following.

- Send a response string "exist" to ajax.
- The ajax, inside the .done() function, will execute a prompt that says "This record already exist, do you wish to overright"?
- If the user canceled the prompt, nothing more should happened and the ajax call should be done.
- If the user clicks "ok", I would like the php script to be notified of this and execute an update statement using the data from form.php.

I suspect this is impossible because after receiving a response from php, AFAIK there is no way for ajax to respond back to the php script that is currently executing.

Am I correct or there is a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a parameter to your ajax request, like `override` with `true` and `false`. By default/first request you set it to `false`. Then the add.php does it's default and returns `exists`.

The the user makes his decision. If he want to override, you send the ajax request again with the `override` parameter to `true`. Your add.php will notice the parameter and does whatever it has to do.

Wrap your ajax handler in an own function with a done callback. So you can reuse the request as often as you want. Pretty easy, no double code needed as well ...

Comment: You should probably not rely on javascript for that as visitors could post directly using the `override` parameter.

Comment: That remains to the script and where to use. The add.php should have the security function to check everything. The user has the decision to override it, so the choice already is by the user ...

Comment: True, but like I said, *probably*; I just tend to keep those kinds of checks as much server-side as possible to avoid potential problems :-)

Answer (score 0):

The `.done()` function of your first ajax call executes when the ajax call has finished successfully, so when your php script has finished completely.

If you want to do something else, you would need to make a new ajax request. That could be to the same or another script, sending in different / new / additional parameters.

Note that you have to make sure that the second script cannot be called without the first one finishing, for example by setting and checking an expiring session variable.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this.

```
 $.post('add.php',$(this).serialize())
.done(function(result){
 var r = confirm("This record already exist, do you wish to overright");
 if(result == 'exist'){
        if (r == true) {
        $.post('update.php',$(this).serialize()).done(function(r){
            console.log(r);
        });
    } else {
        return false;
    }
 }else{
    console.log(result)
 }

});
```